# Symfony: Multiple similar bundles with one master?

Tags: symfony

Let's say I have created a news portal bundle "NewsBundle" with articles, tags, events, lots of relations, quite huge and complex.

Now I want to copy this numerous times and create a Fashion News Portal, Car News Portal, Dog News portal and so on each available though an own domain. The portals **differ only in** **templates**, **translations** and **assets**. As I want to implement complex reporting, I want all the stuff in a single database and would flag all entities with the respective portal.

My question: How so I organize the code?

First I figured out, I could **use routing** to have the same application but **different bundles for each domain**.

Then I found out, that I could **extend my master bundle**. But it seems as this works only once.

As I did all the routing with annotations, it look like it does not work to inherit the routes from the master?

One of the hardest questions is where to put the portal switch. Somewhere I need to set a variable that tells whether its the fashion or dogs portal, so I can filter the content in all repositories accordingly.

I did that in the app.php which is for sure worst practise.

In the end I want to be able to roll out new portals easily without duplicate code.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Greetings from Hamburg,
Boris

Comment: I learned that I can add .yml config files to a bundle. There I could store the bundle's portal ID.

From the posts I read, extending the master means I can't get the routes from the parent bundle. So I guess I have to rewrite all routes from annotation to yml. Then I could store them in the child bundle and inherit them. RIght?

Comment: Are the routes for these portals going to be the same? How do you plan to distinguish them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved via different environments. Each of your portal is a different environment. You can set up your web server to point different front-controllers depending on the `domain` requested.

Example:

For domain `news.domain.com` your front-controller would be `web/app_news.php`. And it will contain line:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('news', false);
```

It will automatically load config from `app/config/config_news.yml`. In that config you can specify all specific parameters for your portal. You need then just implement your special loader for resources like translations that will load resources from the path specified in `config_news.yml`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to keep your `NewsBundle` in your application, and to have a number of bundles revolving around it, one for each portal you intend to create.

There is no real need for bundle inheritance here. Your portal bundles depends on the `NewsBundle` but don't inherit from it.

Routing configuration, templating, and other behaviours related to a specific portal should go in the related bundle. There is a `Resources` folder in each bundle ; this is where you will need to put specific routing, translation, configuration and templates.

`app/config/routing.yml` is the central routing conf file where you will need to reference all other `routing.yml` file.

As for the switch, well, I can't answer that in detail but I think it should be set up in your server application `apache` or `nginx` (or other...).

Comment: That's good advice. The problem is: The Portals are pretty much the same and it will be around 50 of them. Do I really have to add a new route 50 times or is there a better way?

Comment: If your routes are different every time, why yes. If they are similar, you could use [annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) in your base controller, along with [prefixes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#prefixing-imported-routes), different for each bundle. Once again, not sure how well this would work - I'm not sure routes declared in a base controller would propagate to its children. This would need to be combined with host configuration to work properly though.

Comment: Also, still about the routes, I found [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: About the routes, in my opinion and depending on my own experience, YML format is more readable, more flexible for the prefix strategy and it keeps the routing logic in the same place.